# Formatting Table Setting In R

Tags: r

I want to plot a visual table in R. My problem is after I create the visual table I would like to edit it such that I change the font on the header columns, reduce the font, the color of the box. Same this for the data table, I would like to a have a consistent color, specific font and size. And to be able to format the row headers (the names) such that they are a specific font, size, color, etc. Where do I access all those settings. Can anyone put me in the right direction how I can alter rows or cell/cell of each box on the table??

```
plot.table(x)
structure(c(90, 86, 109, 109), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("Jonathan", "Abe"), c("2001-01-01", "2001-04-01")))
```

[image]

Comment: why this instead of html or latex or markdown?

Comment: I just use what R has to plot tables which is the plot.table() command